# how do I turn OFF Smart lock.

Tags: settings

I was trying to secure me phone. I had turned on pattern. Then thought for extra security I would turn on Smart Lock. Note the pattern lock is gone. I want to feel that I can leave my phone on the coffee table and walk away.

Comment: You can just turn off from the same menu when you set Smart Lock: **Settings - Security - Smart Lock**, then remove any lock set, including turning off *On-body detection**

Answer (score 21):

> Go to Settings—Security.
>
> Under Advanced, tap Trusted agents as shown below.
>
> Tap Smart Lock (Google) to Enable\Disable it. You can also drag the switch to
>   the Right\Left side to Enable\Disable it.

[image: Setting\Security\Trusted Agents]
[image: SmartLock(Google)]

Comment: Don't forget to Click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means this answer is valid, as regarding to http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and http://android.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Not so great UX, Google. It's not easy to turn off this annoying feature.

Comment: This was driving me crazy - my home is 'known' by google, which is ok for maps; but it's automatically a trusted place, unlocking my phone at home (which I don't want). Most posts say to remove the place, but it reappears within minutes. This was how to shut it off completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it on and off in Settings -> Security -> Trust agents